# how to update listView conent using xml online without android market

Tags: android, xml

In my application I have a `listView`. I want to update its content on a regular basis.

I use string XML file in res folder, which contains strings that populate the `listView`. What I want to do is check for an update when the application starts (assume I have my own updating system on private server), if update is found:

Download new XML file with the new strings, update them in the `listView`.

From what I read you can't just simply replace the XML files in the res folder.

How can I update the `listView` content from external XML? Or is there a better way to do it other than this?

Why do I want this? Since I am only updating small content, I don't want the user to download the whole APK file instead of few lines of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your xml file in internal storage of application, and whenever you get update just replace your xml file.

Comment: thanks for the answer even tho i dont know how to implement this,you directed me to the right idea

Comment: @Maghster - put your file in data/data/<package name>/files directory, and use it, now whenever you get update for this file using file operation or replacing the file can solve your problem.

Comment: i @user370305 managed to get the xml file in data/data/<package name>/files directory now to use it in all of my activities do i need to read it from cache or i have to read from the file in each activity?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your activity,
Use the following functions to update a file.

```
public synchronized void writeXML(String data) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    fOut = openFileOutput("yourData.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    app.setXMLSize(data.length());
    osw.write(data);
    osw.close();
    fOut.close();

}

private synchronized String readXML() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = openFileInput("yourData.txt");
    try {
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc
                .size());
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```